# Do Pokemon repelling effects stack?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

Sometimes you just don't want to buy more repels. Using the [Black Flute](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Flute#Black_Flute), leading with a Pokemon with [Intimidate](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Intimidate_(Ability)) or [Keen Eye](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Keen_Eye_(Ability)), and equipping your lead with a [Cleanse Tag](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Out-of-battle_effect_item#Cleanse_Tag) all decrease the encounter rate of Pokemon by a percentage. Do these effects stack?